# Resources for operator algebraists interested in understanding category theory?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, operator-algebras, online-resources

Just wondering if there are any resources for learning category theory that might be particularly interesting or helpful for someone mainly studying things under the umbrella of operator algebras. I've tried Googling but couldn't find anything super helpful in the first few hits.

I've just come across the [Hitchhiker's Guide to Categorical Banach Space Theory](https://www.eweb.unex.es/eweb/extracta/Vol-25-2/25J2Castillo.pdf) which certainly looks like it could be useful. But are  there are any resources for learning Category Theory with examples focused on categories of C*-algebras or something like that?

Edit: I should add that I'm a complete beginner to category theory. I'm a grad student and the only time I've come across it in my courses is from my Topology I professor, who spent one lecture trying to put some stuff from our course into the language of category theory. But it was more of an "aside" than anything else.

Comment: Maybe Lawvere's Ph.D. thesis could interest you: http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/5/tr5abs.html